# Find an element in an array, return found if found, else return not found

Tags: c++

I am writing a simple function which iterates over the elements in an array. If the element is found, it returns or prints "element found", if not returns value not found.

My mind in blank right now. Help!

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int arr[] = {1,11,111};
    int size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);

    int option = 999;
    int i = 0;
    if(arr[i] != '\0'){
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++){
            if(arr[i] == option){
                cout << "found" << endl;
                break;
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        }
        cout << "not found" <<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

it is returning both found and not found.

Comment: Well, after it prints "found", the `break` statement exits from the loop, and the very next statement, after the loop, is to print "not found", so that's what happens. Which part of this process you're unsure of, and are asking about?

Comment: *I am writing a simple function which iterates over the elements in an array* -- I do not see a function except for `main`.  If you really did write a function, then you probably wouldn't have the issues you're having now.

Comment: how do i print "found" while it finds element and exit, and if not found just print not found and exit?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie isn't main a function too?

Comment: @S.Sharma -- When you say `write a function`, it has a particular meaning in C++.  You did not write any function -- all you did was stick a bunch of code in `main`.  A function is something that you can *call* with 0 or more arguments, and return a result (if not a `void` function).

Comment: not even a single comment has been a help.

Comment: [Cannot duplicate with your data](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/23c31fa29892e5e2).  Also note the indentation used -- it should now be obvious the code flow that is taken if an element is actually found.  You unconditionally will print "not found", since exiting the loop only takes you to the second `cout` unconditionally.  This is a matter of you needing to follow your code logic more carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get both outputs because that is what your code does. When you find a match, you output "found" and then `break` the loop, moving on with the rest of the program. And then regardless of what the loop did or did not find, you *unconditionally* output "not found".

There are several ways you can address this.

Set a flag before breaking the loop, and don't output until the loop is finished:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int arr[] = {1,11,111};
    int size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);

    int option = 999;
    bool found = false;

    if (arr[i] != '\0'){
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            if (arr[i] == option){
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (found) 
        cout << "found" << endl;
    else
        cout << "not found" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Or simply `return` immediately when a match is found:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int arr[] = {1,11,111};
    int size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);

    int option = 999;

    if (arr[i] != '\0'){
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            if (arr[i] == option){
                cout << "found" << endl;
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "not found" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Or don't search manually, use the standard `std::find()` algorithm instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int arr[] = {1,11,111};
    int size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    int *arrEnd = &arr[size];

    int option = 999;

    if (find(arr, arrEnd, option) != arrEnd)
        cout << "found" << endl;
    else
        cout << "not found" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Any way to reach out to you, direct message?

Comment: You could start by accepting the answer as the correct one.

Comment: @c0d3 StackOverflow doesn't have a direct-messaging system. But there is a contact page on the website linked in my StackOverflow profile.